# Incorporate continuous group level variable in a hierarchical model?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, regression-coefficients

I aim to assess the effects of difficulty (continuous variable) and trial type (0/1) on whether a subject has been correct in a logistic regression model. However, I have also measured subjects impulsivity scores, which is a continuous variable. For impulsivity I only have one estimate per subject, for the other variables I have trial type dependent estimates.

So far I have estimated a logistic regression model per subject, normalized all coefficients by the vector norm of the weight vector per subject and correlated the regression coefficients with the impulsivity scores on a group level. 
I wondered whether this is a reasonable approach? I could also estimate a single mixed effect model and incorporate subject as a random factor. However, there is again no way to incorporate the continuous variable impulsivity in that model, right? How would you proceed with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a mixed effects logistic regression you can include both categorical and continuous covariates that may or may not change within a subject.

Comment: So you would add a vector of num trials*num_subjects that just repeats the impulsivity score trial times per subject?

Comment: It would be the same as including the sex of the subject, i.e., it remains the same for all measurements of a particular subject.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help! I will try that.